# How to get all Storage ID to Authorize with VM ID..?

Tags: api, rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to authorize a storage with VMs. For that I need to have all the VM ID's for a storage and those I get using the following call:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/9653497/getAllowableVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName]
```

This gives me all the VM ID's corresponding to 9653497 (storage/order ID). However, I need to have all those storage ID's (like 9653497) which are not assigned to any of the VM's ID. I am using below call to get all storage ID:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType, billingItem[description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"nasType":{"operation":"ISCSI"},"billingItem":{"description":{"operation":"Endurance Storage"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter in your request, gets `Block Storage`("nasType":{"operation":"ISCSI"}), maybe you need the `File Storage`. We can remove it to get more `"Endurance"` items (Block and File).

Please try the following removing some filters:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType, billingItem[description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={   "networkStorage": {     "billingItem": {       "description": {         "operation": "Endurance Storage"       }     }   } }

Method: GET
```

if we don't want to get only `Endurance`, we can remove that filter too.

But when trying to add some properties using `objectMasks` to [SoftLayer_Account::getNetworkStorage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage) like `allowableVirtualGuests`, that property is not present in `SoftLayer_Network_Storage`.

For that reason the unique way to get “getAllowableVirtualGuests” is using [SoftLayer_Network_Storage::getAllowableVirtualGuests](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowableVirtualGuests)

Answer (score 0):

the data that you are using for the filter probably are wrong, try to call the get object method `GET /SoftLayer_Network_Storage/9653497/getObject?objectMask=mask[nasType,billingItem[description]]` and see if the values of the request are the same as of your objectFilter